# Shortcut to Navigate back in visual studio 2010 and resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, shortcut, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm just getting back to `visual studio 2010` after using `phpStorm`(jetBrain's product) and I'm missing all the nice shortcut keys.  I've installed `visual studio 2010` with `resharper` but am still missing some of the nice features.  I can't figure out how to "navigate back" in my code. For example if I'm navigating to various method definitions and then I want to navigate back to where I just was how do I do this?

I believe that in `phpstorm` I would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to go navigate back and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> if I wanted to go forward.  It would keep a history so I could just keep going back as far as I wanted.  Please help. I miss this feature.

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl -`?

Comment: And after you go back with `Ctrl -`, you can go forward again with `Ctrl Shift -`

Comment: Thanks!  If one of you want to answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default, you can navigate back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and navigate forward with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

If you want to change these shortcuts, go to Tools->Options...->Environment->Keyboard, then search for the commands called `View.NavigateBackward` and `View.NavigateForward`, and assign them new keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details.

Comment: Note: `-` is not the minus sign but dash character.

Comment: @FredrickGauss They aren't the same thing?

Comment: @JenS, For the sake of VS navigation shortcut, they are not the same. At least for me; `Ctrl`+ `-(minus sign in Num Pad area)` is not working.

Comment: @FredrickGauss The minus characters are the same. The **keybindings** however are not. ~ `ctrl + numpad minus` is a different binding than `ctrl + minus`

Comment: That's crazy, would have never guessed :)

Comment: Thanks, it is difficult to find these sorts of shortcuts when you don't know the name to search for.

Answer (score 0):

In Resharper 2020.02 it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> to go back in 'time' and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> to go forward respectively.