# Back and forth navigation, similar to browsers, in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can navigate between documents, but what about a back button similar to a browser?

**Example:** If I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to navigate to a method's declaration, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> both will not bring me back to the method's reference I had highlighted beforehand.

What short cut provides this back and forth functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will navigate forward and backwards.

Comment: Ha. No problem. Never realized that there was an accept delay enforced. FWIW, I just use the two nav icons in the toolbar... and I use them CONSTANTLY.

Comment: Too bad it wasn't the same as browsers, ALT left arrow and ALT right arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I just found from the comments on [Shortcut to Navigate back in visual studio 2010 and resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068336/shortcut-to-navigate-back-in-visual-studio-2010-and-resharper) that the answer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (back) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (forward).